# About Java HashMap sources

Tags: java, hashmap

So, we have a HashMap, and a transient Entry[] table inside it. In many methods, for example, in clear(), we copy table:

```
public void clear() {
    modCount++;
    Entry[] tab = table;
    for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++)
        tab[i] = null;
    size = 0;
}
```

But why we do Entry[] tab = table? What's wrong in next code?

```
public void clear() {
    modCount++;
    for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++)
        table[i] = null;
    size = 0;
}
```

As far as i know, tab is only a reference to table, and, for at first sight, is just a wasting of space.

Comment: Wasting what space?  Method-local variables are cheap and go away as soon as the method is complete.  This is an example of a technique -- less necessary in modern JVMs, but necessary when `HashMap` was originally written -- to cache object fields in local variables for speed.

Comment: You don't **copy** the `table`. This is not C++, there is no copy constructor or anything involved. You're operating on references and references only. The cost of this assignment is next to nothing.

Comment: Louis Wasserman, could you please explain, how caching object fields in local variables can speed up?
Daniel Kamil Kozar, yes, i know this.

Answer (score 1):

```
 for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++)
        tab[i] = null;
```

You are right, `tab` and `table` both point to the same object.  The problem I see is using table in the for-conditional and tab in the for-body.  You should use one or the other, but not both.

`tab` is unnecessary, but sometimes people do this for readability reasons.   Doesn't make sense here, since table is more readable.  If I were code reviewing this, I would strongly prefer the second version.

Comment: I think it's just a typo, he most certainly means it to be `table[i] = null;` in the second example.

Comment: yes, forgot about it. Fixed tab[i] = null; => table[i] = null;

Answer (score 0):

It's just one locally scoped object reference. Not a lot of space there.